# Is this a normal exception from JOGL FPSAnimator?

Tags: java, exception, jogl, frame-rate

Whenever my program processes the line:

```
animator.start();
```

it produces the exception like error:

```
FPSAnimator P1:Thread[main-FPSAWTAnimator-Timer0,5,main]: Task[thread Thread[main-FPSAWTAnimator-Timer0,5,main], stopped false, paused false shouldRun true, shouldStop false -- started true, animating true, paused false, drawable 1, drawablesEmpty false]
```

I dont understand why this occurs. The program works just as it is intended, but this exception occurs and I am wondering what is happening and why it occurs. Is it just a self status? Can I just ignore it?
When I also call the stop method it produces a similar exception just with different booleans set to false. Can I just ignore this?

Im also using eclipse to run my code. Thanks

-Dan

Comment: Are you sure that it's an `Exception` and not just a regular `System.out.println();` ?

Comment: Well its red, so im just wonding if its normal or not.

Comment: For printing red text or errors, you can just do `System.err.println();`, but that doesn't make it an error. Do you actually catch an exception or does the text just randomly popup in the console?

Comment: Im not printing out a red message. I guess it just randomly pops up? Well its not random, it happens once I call the start method of the FPSAnimator. But it doesnt do anything that I can see to my program, I have stepped through my program to check out and I didnt see anything. It runs how it is suppose to run but the message just pops up. Im just curious and would like to know why it does pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a debug statement that was mistakenly left in the final build.